# Returning only selected fields from an API call

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-core-webapi

How can I apply JSON filtering to a response in ASP.NET Core Web API?

I have an endpoint which is using the HTTP Get verb and returning more than 80 fields in JSON, but I want to return only the fields which are requested by the client, based on some where conditions.

How can I implement this, and how to pass parameters for **selector** and **filtering** from a client (e.g. postman, swagger)?

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/cards")]
public IActionResult Cards(inputParameters,selector,filtering)
{
return OK(----)
}
```

In the **selector**, the client passes the fields they want in response and in the **filtering**, the client passes the parameter for a where condition.

For example, I'm returning an employee object which has 5 fields:

- Id
- Name
- DOB
- Address
- Subject

In one request, the client only wants two fields (Name and DOB). In another request, the client wants three fields (Subject,Id,Address).

Comment: Could you provide an example of the `selector`?

Comment: You might look into GraphQL. "It is a query language for APIs and a runtime for fulfilling those queries with your existing data. GraphQL provides a complete and understandable description of the data in your API, gives clients the power to ask for exactly what they need and nothing more, makes it easier to evolve APIs over time, and enables powerful developer tools."

Comment: OData is a competing standard to GraphQL and enables the same features. If you're using Entity Framework, you'll enjoy the deepest integration with that using OData. GraphQL is more generic, so will require more effort to set up, but can also work with other data providers and sources. Either is a good option and will enable what you're looking for.

Comment: @Haytam the fields which client wants  in response for example I'm returning student object which is having 5 fields(Id,Name,DOB,Address,Subject) but in a request client only wants two fields(Name and DOB) in another request he want three fields(Subject,Id,Address) so on ..

Comment: Yep. Then you definitely want either OData or GraphQL.

Comment: I would also suggest GraphQL.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I'm using Entity Framework (EF) Core so which is more feasible  OData or GraphQL.

Comment: OData support is virtually drop in with Entity Framework. It's definitely the easiest way forward for that dependency. GraphQL is not without merit, but you'll need to directly setup how it gets its data, since it's agnostic about the provider. In short, GraphQL gives you more flexibility, but OData is easiest for EF.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `ViewModel` and return it in it.

For example:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }

    public string Property2 { get; set; }

    public int Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

And then in your `GET` action:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/cards")]
public IActionResult Cards(inputParameters,selector,filtering)
{
    return OK(new ViewModel 
           { 
                Property1 = FromJson.Something, 
                Property2 = FromJson.Something44, 
                Property3 = FromJson.Something79 
           });
}
```

By view models classes you can make return in `JSON` style with propertys like you want to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Automapper library, and map a model to a ViewModel, by setting a Mapping profile Class.

First, add [Automapper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper/) and [Automapper dependency injection](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection/) packages.

Then Add Automapper to the startup class:

```
    public class Startup
{
    // Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
Mapper.Reset(); // Useful if you're using code-first and migrations.
services.AddAutomapper();
    }

    // Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Create your ViewModel, with only the needed properties to send to the front-end app.

```
public class CardViewModel
{
public object PropVM1 {get; set;}
public object PropVM2 {get; set;}
public object PropVM3 {get; set;}
...
}
```

From a Model class:

```
public class Card
    {
    public object Prop1 {get; set;}
    public object Prop2 {get; set;}
    public object Prop3 {get; set;}
    public object Prop4 {get; set;}
    public object Prop5 {get; set;}
    ...
    }
```

Then create a mapping profile class, that inherit from AutoMapper.Profile:

```
public class AppMappingProfile : Profile
{
public AppMappingProfile()
{
CreateMap<Card, CardViewModel>()
   .ForMember(d => d.PropVM1, ex => ex.MapFrom(o => o.Prop1))
   .ForMember(d => d.PropVM2, ex => ex.MapFrom(o => o.Prop2))
   .ForMember(d => d.PropVM3, ex => ex.MapFrom(o => o.Prop3))
   .ReverseMap() // if a two-away Mapping is necessary
}
}
```

Finally, add Automapper to your controller:

```
public class CardController : Controller
{
private readonly IMapper;
public CardController(IMapper mapper)
{
_mapper = mapper;
}
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/cards")]
public IActionResult Cards(inputParameters,selector,filtering)
{
var result = DoYourThing();

//if a list of cards
if(result != null && result.Count > 0) return Ok(_mapper.Map<List<Card>, List<CardViewModel>>(result));
return NoContent();

// if single card object
if(result != null) return Ok(_mapper.Map<Card, CardViewModel>())
return NoContent();
}

}
```

Comment: it's useful when you have to return certain fields every time but in my requirement its dynamic for example I'm returning employee object which is having 5 fields(Id,Name,DOB,Address,Subject) but in a request client only wants two fields(Name and DOB) in another request he want three fields(Subject,Id,Address) so on ....

Comment: Ok got it, have you thought about ExpandoObject from System.Dynamic assembly?you can use it to create dynamic object (dynamic obj = new ExpandoObject(); obj.Prop1 = "value";... and so on). check https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score -1):

You could return a `Dictionary<string, object>` and add the fields you want as entries like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/v1/cards")]
public IActionResult Cards(inputParameters,selector,filtering)
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    result["variable1"] = "value1";
    if (something == true)
        result["variable2"] = 7;
    return OK(result);
}
```

Comment: The fields the user wants are in `selector` so setting them manually won't help.

Comment: Then you do `if (selector.Contains("variable2")) result["variable2"] = 7;`.

Answer (score -1):

I solve the issue by using **OData**, its awesome.
You can go through the link to implement OData in your .net core api 
[Supercharging your Web APIs with OData and ASP.NET Core](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/On-NET/Supercharging-your-Web-APIs-with-OData-and-ASPNET-Core)

Comment: This is really more a comment. It does not say much more than "I solved my problem by solving my problem".